# Ubuntu 18.04.02, default (Gnome) spin, live session: am I right in thinking one can't change theme, fonts?

Tags: gnome, themes, fonts

I'm trying out the default (Gnome) spin of Ubuntu and I'm liking it a lot so far, except that it seems I can't change the theme or the fonts. Now, Gnome lockdown hasn't gone so far that I will not be able to change those things if I actually *install* Ubuntu - *right*?

Comment: Hi,  can you explain little more what are you trying to achieve and what you tried so far? spin means what? and are you talking about try Ubuntu option?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 'Spin' means 'flavour' i.e. desktop environment - Gnome, XFCE, Plasma, etc. What I am trying to achieve: I'd like, on the live (pre-install) session, to change theme and fonts (just play around with them, to see whether I can get something I like); failing that, I want to be reassured that if I actually install the OS I can change those things. What I tried: I found the system settings menu and looked through it and searched for 'font' and 'theme'.

Comment: PRATAP: yes, I want to change themes and fonts in a live session. I've said that now twice. But, and as I have said also, my *main* concern is to know whether I can do that if I install the thing. Have I already chosen any particular themes and fonts? No. As I said, I just want to play around.

Comment: Please do not ask leading questions. If your question is "*am I right in thinking one can't change theme, fonts?*" OR "... *I will not be able to change those things if I actually install Ubuntu - right?*", then a simple "**No.**" would be a perfectly valid answer. We only support [practical, objectively answerable questions](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) here, e.g. "*how can I change theme, fonts in live session?*" and so on; **[edit]** your question to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are in livesession

1. Connect to Internet
2. run `sudo add-apt-repository universe`
3. run `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`
4. Open `gnome-tweaks`

[image]

[image]

5. Play with the fonts and themes which are available out of box.. Or you can download from the web and play..

Example:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nmcli device wifi list
IN-USE  SSID         MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
        PRATAP       Infra  11    270 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2     
        iBall-Baton  Infra  5     270 Mbit/s  12      ▂___  WPA1     
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ nmcli device wifi connect PRATAP
Device 'wlp2s0' successfully activated with '9bfef13f-b77a-442c-aa9c-fa3db9177f12'.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-tweaks
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
'universe' distribution component enabled for all sources.
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.2 2019.06.06 LTS amd64 _Custom Bionic Beaver_ (20190606) bionic InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.2 2019.06.06 LTS amd64 _Custom Bionic Beaver_ (20190606) bionic Release
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]      
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [382 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages [8570 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [137 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [14.9 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [10.4 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [20.9 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted amd64 Packages [4296 B]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted Translation-en [2192 B]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [257 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [145 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [35.8 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16.4 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [95.7 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe Translation-en [4941 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3287 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [2151 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [8420 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [641 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [237 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [276 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [66.7 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [123 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [6996 B]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [945 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [279 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [227 kB]
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [190 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [395 kB]
Fetched 32.1 MB in 21s (1540 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-tweaks
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 424 not upgraded.
Need to get 218 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1245 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 gnome-tweaks all 3.28.1-1 [218 kB]
Fetched 218 kB in 11s (19.1 kB/s)                   
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-tweaks.
(Reading database ... 143252 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-tweaks_3.28.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-tweaks (3.28.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Setting up gnome-tweaks (3.28.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

6. to play with shell themes, you need to Install `User-Themes` gnome-shell extension.. to install it.. try from `Software` if Its not Installing.. then run the below commands

`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com']"
```

7. Close `gnome-tweaks`
8. Refresh the shell Alt+F2 type r and press enter..

[image]

9. Now you can play with shell themes also..